# Cant connect to sql server with mysql-connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to connect to mySQL using mysql-connector and I'm getting an error:

> runfile('C:/Users/Idan/Desktop/תכנות/ניסויים/idk/adding_test/connect_to_db.py', >wdir='C:/Users/Idan/Desktop/תכנות/ניסויים/idk/adding_test')
> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\Idan\Desktop\תכנות\ניסויים\idk\adding_test\connect_to_db.py", >line 13, in 
> database = 'temp'

> File "C:\Users\Idan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector_*init*_.py", >line 271, in connect
> return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)

> File "C:\Users\Idan\anaconda3\lib\site->packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in **init**
> self._in_transaction = False

> File "C:\Users\Idan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", >line 985, in connect
> self._open_connection()

> File "C:\Users\Idan\anaconda3\lib\site->packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 205, in _open_connection
> ssl_options.get('verify_identity') or

> File "C:\Users\Idan\anaconda3\lib\site->packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 193, in _get_connection
> if client_flags & ClientFlag.SSL:

> File "C:\Users\Idan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", >line 565, in **init**
> super(MySQLTCPSocket, self).**init**()

> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

I have tried searching online and I can't find problem with my code (and yes the password is correct):

```
import mysql.connector as mysql

db = mysql.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = '10iDun7lEvy3',
    database = 'temp'
    )

c = db.cursor()
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are running this code with the right Python version?

Comment: my current version is 3.7.6, im not sure if its the right one since im pretty new to programming. I just finished learning SQL and now im trying to use it together with pythom with the syntax i found online @snakecharmerb

Comment: Try doing `import sys;print(sys.version_info)` in the code before you try to connect to the database

Comment: it doesnt change anything except printing `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)` @snakecharmerb

Comment: it printed what i wrote in the last comment: `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)` @snakecharmerb

Comment: I don't know what's going on then.  What is the value of `mysql.connector.version.VERSION`?

Comment: (8, 0, 22, '', 1) @snakecharmerb